# <tag> property confusion (SCM, release:prepare)

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin, maven-scm

What is the difference between [`scm:tag`](https://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/tag-mojo.html):

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:code.stuff.com/scm/project/repo.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@code.stuff.com:7999/project/repo.git</developerConnection>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>
```

and [`release:prepare:tag:`](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#tag)?

I read that during the `release:prepare` goal, user is prompted with the desired tag-name to stick; after preparation is successfully completed, Maven will tag the release candidate in the VCS with the passed name. At this point, what is the use of `scm:tag`?

Comment: `scm:tag` will "only" perform a tag operation on the SCM system, where `release:prepare` will perform various tasks, included a tag operation on the SCM system. Sometimes you only want to perform the tag operation, without all the other things the `release:prepare` mojo does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<scm><tag>` is not used, the release:prepare will create a tag in SCM using the version.

I would delete it and let it choose the default, which is the  in the pom (**WITH THE SNAPSHOT REMOVED**).

Comment: So, the value of <tag> is uniquely chosen when running the release:prepare goal (the user is prompted for it). And afterwards the goal is sticking such value into the pom.xml under <scm>/<tag> just to store this information?

Comment: Exactly, so start of without it, and let the release plugin do it's work.